# GWT module may need to be (re)compiled REMOTE debugging

Tags: java, maven, gwt, glassfish

Hello I have a problem debugging my GWT application from a remote computer once I run the GWT dev mode. Everything works fine when i go to

```
127.0.0.1:8888/TestApp.html?gwt.codesrv=127.0.0.1:9997
```

however when I go to

```
192.168.1.142:8888/TestApp.html?gwt.codesrv=192.168.1.142:9997
```

on the other computer in the network I get a popup saying "GWT module 'TestApp' may need to be (re)compiled.

I'm using GWT/Maven/Glassfish EJB for this project and I can't seem to wrap my mind around why it works locally and not remotely.

Here is my GWT Run configuration for eclipse:

```
-port 8888 -war /Users/abc123/Documents/workspace/path/to/snapshotfolder -remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -startupUrl TestApp.html -logLevel INFO -bindAddress 0.0.0.0 -codeServerPort 9997 com.abc.def.gwt.TestApp
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried to Run your app like this:
192.168.1.142:8888/TestApp.html

don't use 8888 port use your tomcat port or and other server your using means use that server's port.

Comment: Hello and thanks for answering! I tried to run the url without the gwt.codesrv parameter but I still get the same result. I'm not sure I understand what you mean?